# Best way to add Facebook login to site without noticeably redirecting

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First, I'd like to say this isn't a general question on the Facebook php/javascript sdk. I've successfully added the "Facebook login button" to a few little test projects.

My question is, what is the best way to show the user is *wanting* to log in with Facebook. Just because someone is logged in to Facebook when the visit my site, doesn't necessarily mean they want to login to my site *with* Facebook.

I know that after authorizing the user with a FB app, it redirects with a variety of `$_GET` variables, but if my user is returning to my site, and has already authorized my app, how can I create a "Facebook Login" button that basically 'says' `If user clicks this button, pull Facebook user_profile, and use their info for login, else require Facebook login as normal`.

I know I could create a button, forward to a page, set a session var, and redirect to the main page, but I'd like to create this effect without noticeable redirections; no redirections if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `FB.getLoginStatus`. You'll asynchronously get a response telling you the auth state, and you can manually go from there (show their info, log them in, redirect if you want, etc).

From the SDK reference (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the documentation here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

there is a param for the javascript facebook api init function which checks the user status, using that you can see if the user has already auth'd your app and is logged in. if the status shows they are an auth'd user you can store the user object but don't change any of the UI to show you have that information.

when the user clicks the login button, you already have their info.

I suppose the problem you are trying to solve is how you open a PHP session for that user?